# Database Address table design with unique Addresses

Tags: sql-server, database, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I'm designing a database in which I've Addresses related to Customers. According to the rules of Object Oriented Programming an Address can exist independently without customer and many customers can have same address and a customer can also have multiple addresses. So I've created Many-to-Many relationship between Customer & Address. My tables are as following:
[ERD of Customer Address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBTi5.png)

Now this design requires the addresses in **Address** table to be unique to conform to the real world and this is the challenge I'm facing now.
I've thought of a solution which is to use [Google's Autocomplete for Addresses](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete) and lookup the Addresses from it. If the entered address will be new then I'll insert it into **Address** table and if it is already present in database then I'll only insert record in **CustomerAddress** table for association. Now I've two questions:

**1)** Is the solution I'm thinking of valid? I've doubt about it since I haven't seen such an implementation anywhere?

**2)** The above solution only solves the problem till **AddressLine1** and not **AddressLine2** which is normally Floor & Appartment/Office/Shop number. I don't know any API which provides unique values for **AddressLine2** for lookup. Then how can I keep the combination of **AddressLine1** & **AddressLine2** unique?

Comment: Can't you simply use an EXISTS query?

Comment: Your data structure looks good. The issue of keeping them unique is to simply add a unique constraint for AddressLine1 and AddressLine2. The issue you are describing is in regards to cleaning the address data. You can use the autocomplete to help, but it will not enforce users to use the autocompleted address. Cleaning addresses is a huge issue for transportation metrics and if you figure out an easy way then please share it. As far as I know, you either have to accept dirty data or get more granular with street, zip, city, state, unit, etc... and you still can have dirty data.

Comment: @AndrewO'Brien Yes, you got it right. By unique address I actually meant clean data. Because one address can be typed in many different ways e.g., 51 First Street, Cambridge, MA, USA **OR** First Street 51, Cambridge, MA, USA. I agree with your idea of granularity. Can you provide such an example which breaks down address into granular components.

Comment: Assuming it is a US address, I would have entries for Street, City, State, Zip, and an additional entry for unit/suite/office. This will not clean it, but could allow you to build your own logic to clean it or feed it to an API that cleans it for you. These are offered online but are not free. You can take a look at https://smartystreets.com/products/apis/us-street-api to see how they break it down. Best of luck on this.